# how to search by clicking on suggestions in react

Tags: reactjs, search

Hi I am trying to make a search bar where you can search items by typing or clicking on the drop-down suggestions.
I am currently using useNavigate, useState and useLocation to do this.
Currently I am struggling with the clicking dropdown menus because the state "search" keeps reading from the input NOT the clicked suggestion.

If I click on the dropdown menu the input automatically fills with the item name but if I look at the searched name, its same as the name that I actually typed.

e.g If I only type blue, the drop down blueshirt comes up and if I click it, it shows me that I searched for "blue" instead of "blueshirt".

```
    const handleSearch = (searchTerm) => {
    console.log(searchTerm)
    setSearch(searchTerm)
    navigate('/search', { state: { search, items } });
    window.location.reload();
  }



     return (

       <input 
        type="text"
        value={search}
        placeholder='Search'
        onChange={(e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value)
        }}
        onKeyDown={handleSearchEnter}
        />


       <div className="dropdown">
         {
          items
           .filter((item) => {
             const searchTerm = search.toLowerCase();
             const fullName = item.name.toLowerCase();

             return searchTerm && fullName.startsWith(searchTerm) && item.name !== 
              searchTerm
                })
                .map((item) =>
                  <div
                    key={item.id}
                    value={item.name}
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleSearch(item.name)
                    }}
                    className='dropdown-row'
                  >{item.name}</div>
                )
            }
          </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `setState` will not take effect until re-render. So your search uses the old value. The solution is to store the new search in a variable and use it immediately or simply use `searchTerm`:

```
    const handleSearch = (searchTerm) => {
    console.log(searchTerm)
    setSearch(searchTerm)
    navigate('/search', { state: { searchTerm, items } });
    window.location.reload();
  }
```